# Are x<=y and x-y<=0 equivalent in floating point arithmetic?

Tags: math, floating-point, numerical

Assume that x,y are two floating point numbers. Then is that true:

```
x<=y <==> x-y<=0
```

in floating point arithmetic?

Thank for your ideas.

**[Edit]** Let us assume, additionally, that neither x nor y are `NaN`.

Is that possible that x<=y holds but not x-y<=0 or x-y<=0 holds but not x<=y.

Comment: @Paul R:  The NaN cases are excluded now (see edits above), so my question is more about dealing with "normal" floating point numbers.

Comment: The only NaN case that matters is where `x == y` and both are an infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Note: I'm ignoring infinities and NaNs in this answer, as either trivially leads to non-equivalence.]*

If you've disabled subnormal numbers (or flush-to-zero behaviour), then it's possible to produce an underflow with the subtraction, resulting in non-equivalence between your two expressions.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CSR_FLUSH_TO_ZERO (1 << 15)

// Note: GCC-specific
void disable_ftz(void) {
    unsigned csr = __builtin_ia32_stmxcsr();
    csr |= CSR_FLUSH_TO_ZERO;
    __builtin_ia32_ldmxcsr(csr);
}

int main(void) {
    disable_ftz();

    float x = 2.8e-45;
    float y = 1.4e-45;

    printf("%e\n", x);           // 2.802597e-45
    printf("%e\n", y);           // 1.401298e-45

    printf("%d\n", x <= y);      // 0
    printf("%d\n", (x-y) <= 0);  // 1
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this requires some compiler-specific magic on an x86.  However, it's permissible to have a floating-point implementation that doesn't have subnormals at all, and on such systems no magic would be required to achieve the same non-equivalence.

Comment: It's clearly impossible for subtraction to underflow if you have gradual underflow; that's the point of gradual underflow.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Sure, but "gradual underflow" (AKA denormals) have their limits.  Of course, the only way to produce a number that's smaller than the smallest denormal would be to have `x` and `y` differ by that value, which is impossible :)